# ios - FontAwesome.swift how to use more icons

Tags: ios, swift, font-awesome

I was using an older version of FontAwesome.swift, but I did update it recently, and I've lost some of icons. There is Enum.swift file in pod FontAwesome.swift folder, which stores all icons codes. And in current version there are missing a lot of icons I was using before. I would ask this question on their's github, but questions are not available in there. Is there any way to get this icons? Or any other icons from FontAwesome?

Comment: Create a new [issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues)

Comment: https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift This is the pod. And there is now place to create a new issue

Comment: Show your code. What font are you including and what character are you trying to display?

Comment: I had found the reason. Before full heart icon was with code "fa-heart" and heart with empty inside was "fa-heart-o". Now this is changed. They added styles, and both of the hearts are with code "fa-heart" but you need to set style (.brands for the empty one, and .regular for full heart). Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons might not be missed in FontAwesome, It might be renamed.

For Example: `FontAwesome.refresh` renamed to `FontAwesome.redoAlt`

So you can try to find the icon type or name at this [link](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=refresh).

Comment: It was renamed. But not in regular way. They did add styles, and now I have to use styles. For example:  Before full heart icon was with code "fa-heart" and heart with empty inside was "fa-heart-o". Now this is changed. They added styles, and both of the hearts are with code "fa-heart" but you need to set style (.brands for the empty one, and .regular for full heart). Thanks for the help!